# Downloading KEYWORD PERFORMANCE REPORT through AdWords API is slow for TSV files

Tags: java, google-ads-api, google-api-java-client

I have tried to download the **KEYWORD PERFORMANCE** REPORT through AdWords API in TSV & XML formats and it is crawling to finish and sometimes even times out.

```
reportDefinition.setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat.TSV)
```

The same report works well when I use the CSV format and the job finishes in about 5 minutes.

```
reportDefinition.setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat.CSV)
```

In both cases, I am talking about 2.2 million records that I am trying to download through the report. Also, just as a side note, the same TSV worked well with API version 2014 and I am currently using the latest version of the API.

```
import com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.utils.v201708.ReportDownloader
```

I could use the CSV format, but the issue is that some of the fields/columns in the downloaded report contain "commas" and it gets quite messy dealing with all that upstream.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the Adwords reporting backend. I'd suggest posting to the [Adwords API forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api).

Comment: Yes, I have posted this issue on AdWords Forum. Here is the post if someone is interested to follow along.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/lnuRYUwohNw